# Subset of Context Free Language with Strings Starting and Ending in Same Symbol is Context Free

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

This was a question asked in a previous exam that I'm studying. Assume $L$ is a context free language (CFL). Let $L_{a..a}$ be a subset of $L$ s.t. all strings in $L_{a..a}$ start and end with the same character. Prove that $L_{a..a}$ is a CFL.

I tried to use Chomsky Normal form of $L$ but couldn't get anywhere. This can be proved using either grammars or PDA.

Any suggestions how this might be proven?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. If $A$ is the alphabet and $a \in A$, then $L_{a..a} = L \cap aA^*a$.

Comment: Thanks, but using closure properties of CFLs is the only way I think I know how to prove this. Any hints regarding how to prove this using grammar construction or PDAs?

Comment: See this [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18645) for a construction using PDAs.